# How to know if a value exists in three separate lists?

Tags: python, list

If I have three lists of strings like the below how do I iterate through the list in order to identity if a specified ingredient say 'banana' is in any of the lists? I need to define a function that outputs either true or false.

```
menu = [
         ['soup','onion','potato','leek','celery'],
         ['pizza','bread','tomato','cheese','cheese'],
         ['banana']
       ]
```

Comment: I like the one with double cheese :)

Comment: Do you need to do it one one or many times on the same menu?
Do you need to do it on many menus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @ThePyGuy for the logic, but here is a very similar answer, defined as a function.

```
def check_menu(item, menu):
    if any(item in v for v in menu):
        return True
    else:
        return False 

print(check_menu('banana',menu))
True
print(check_menu('mushroom',menu))
False
```

This way you can have it check whatever menu, or item in the menu you want.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed thank you, i haven't come across 'any' before. If it finds the item in the menu in the first list does it stop there or will it continue to iterate through the remaining lists?

Comment: Your menu object is a list of lists, what this function will do is check the ENTIRE menu object and if 'banana' exists inside of menu, then it will return True, so it doesn't matter the location of the item in the list, or which list it is in, within the list of lists. If 'banana' is not in your menu, then it will return False, it iterates through the entire object, yes.

Comment: I have to state about the complexity of the function and the run times of it for increasing size lists. So say for example if the menu is 1000 items long and the item is in position 1 will it still carry on and check the remaining 999 items even though it found it at position 1?

Comment: I think what you are wanting to know is the amount of times something will appear in your menu? Because if you have 1000 items in your menu list, and all this function is doing is searching IF 'banana' exists IN MENU. So if 'banana' is found at position 1, it doesn't matter if it iterates through the entire list, because your function would return True. Does that make sense? Where as if 'banana' is found at index 900, it would also return True, because it EXISTS within Menu, doesn't matter where.

Comment: But to answer your question, the (item in v for v in menu) is iterating through every item, but the function is only checking if that item EXISTS in the menu. So no matter the size of the list it will iterate through the entire list, even if item is found at index 1

Comment: Since `any` returns a boolean, your function reduces to `def check_menu(item, menu): return any(item in v for v in menu)`.  No need for the if/else fluff, it's redundant.

Comment: You are right, thank you for the improvement @pjs

Answer (score 7):

You need to check in each of the sub-lists, you can use `any` built-in passing the generator expression

```py
>>> any('banana' in v for v in menu)
True
```